# Send angular upload file to server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to upload some image file using angularjs, By using angular uploader. I am able to select the image and it is available in scope model also. My requirement is when I post the model through http post the selected image file should be available in one of model property.

Below is the code for selecting the image and storing the image in model property.

```
<button" ng-model="AllDate.StudentPhoto">Upload Photo</button>
```

After selecting I am posting the model to the server and I want that image file inside that model property,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: what should be the data type in server (mvc c#) because it is showing null for object,dynamic,httpfilebase etc